# Define apex:variable in apex:inputText

Tags: visualforce, apex-param, apex-variable, immediate

I'm trying to pass parameters while using immediate=true.
(actionRegion is not an option)

Since this won't work:

```
    <apex:inputText value="{!searchValue}" />
    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!doSearch}" immediate="true"/>
```

I tried to create a variable and use it like this:

```
1: <apex:variable var="input" value="" />
2: <apex:inputText value="{!input}"/>
3: <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!doSearch}" immediate="true">
4:      <apex:param name="value" assignTo="{!searchValue}" value="{!input}" />
5: </apex:commandButton>
```

But in line **2** it tells me

> Save error: Unknown property 'input'

Any idea if there is a way to define this variable with any kind of user input?

Last option would be some hacky JS like: `onblur="setApexVar()"` any experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try something like

```
    <apex:variable var="input" value="" />
     <apex:inputText value="{!input}" styleclass="textCls"/>
     <apex:commandButton value="Search" onclick="passValue()" rerender="none"/>
      <apex:actionfunction action="{!doSearch}" immediate="true" />
          <apex:param name="value" assignTo="{!searchValue}"/>
     </apex:actionfunction>

<script>
   function passValue()
   {
        var val= document.getElementsByClassName('textCls')[0].value;
       actfun(val);

    }
<script>
```

Using this `actionfunction` you can pass value to controller.

**Update:** I am not sure about `actionfunction` but you can remove one script method.

```
     <apex:inputText styleclass="textCls"/>
     <apex:commandButton value="Search" onclick="actfun(document.getElementsByClassName('textCls')[0].value);" rerender="none"/>
      <apex:actionfunction action="{!doSearch}" immediate="true" />
          <apex:param name="value" assignTo="{!searchValue}"/>
     </apex:actionfunction>
```

Comment: I had the same Idea, but it's too hacky for me, since it is using a Button, an Actionfunction and another function, just to pass one string, so I was hoping to find a more native solution

Comment: Tushar.. Have you ever used tooltip help text in vf for salesforce1 ? I am just looking for a solution have you used ever like that something?

Comment: @Ratan no I didn't. But if you can give me some details then I can suggest you any option :)

Comment: @TusharSharma Thanks for your concern. I solved the issue. I just guessing may be your worked on something. Thanks anyways. :)

Comment: Ratan, can you post a new question about the tool tips?